# Determine a date from the position of an event in a string

Tags: sql

Can you give me an idea of how to go about this?

I have a variable STATUS which corresponds to the occurrence of an event day after day (in chronological order between the start date included (DATE_START) and the end date included (DATE_END).
If my character string contains one of the following values: 2,3,6, I need to find the value's position in the string and assign it a date (the character string can contain several events).

[image]

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the picture. SQL is not well suited for these types of tasks, but the engine you are using might have some support for it. Tag your database as a start. And also give sample data (not as a picture, people do not like chasing pictures on SO).

Comment: If this Access, write VBA procedure.